# Suspending function can only be called within coroutine body

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

I'm trying to deliver realtime updates to my view with Kotlin Flows and Firebase.

This is how I collect my realtime data from my `ViewModel`:

```
class MainViewModel(repo: IRepo): ViewModel() {

    val fetchVersionCode = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(Resource.Loading())

        try {
            repo.getVersionCode().collect {
                emit(it)
            }

        } catch (e: Exception){
            emit(Resource.Failure(e))
            Log.e("ERROR:", e.message)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I emit each flow of data from my repo whenever a value changes in Firebase:

```
class RepoImpl: IRepo {

    override suspend fun getVersionCodeRepo(): Flow<Resource<Int>> = flow {

        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("params").document("app").addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
                val versionCode = documentSnapshot!!.getLong("version")
                emit(Resource.Success(versionCode!!.toInt()))
            }
    }
```

The problem is that when I use:

```
 emit(Resource.Success(versionCode!!.toInt()))
```

Android Studio highlights the emit invocation with:

> Suspend function 'emit' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function

But I'm calling this code from a `CoroutineScope` in my `ViewModel`.

What's the problem here?

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Firestore snapshot listener is effectively an asynchronous callback that runs on another thread that has nothing to do with the coroutine threads managed by Kotlin.  That's why you can't call `emit()` inside an asynchronous callback - the callback is simply not in a coroutine context, so it can't suspend like a coroutine.

What you're trying to do requires that you put your call to emit back into a coroutine context using whatever method you see fit (e.g. `launch`), or perhaps start a [callbackFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) that lets you offer objects from other threads.

Comment: i am exploring the Kotlin coroutine as well. Do you know any reference to support your explanation? Thanks!

Comment: @YazidEF here is a very good explanation and example of the problem: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow#create
`With the flow builder, the producer cannot emit values from a different CoroutineContext. Therefore, don't call emit in a different CoroutineContext by creating new coroutines or by using withContext blocks of code. You can use other flow builders such as callbackFlow in these cases.`

Answer (score 6):

The `suspend` keyword on `getVersionCodeRepo()` does not apply to  `emit(Resource.Success(versionCode!!.toInt()))` because it being called from within a lambda.  Since you can't change `addSnapshotListener` you'll need to  use a coroutine builder such as `launch` to invoke a `suspend` function.

When a lambda is passed to a function, the declaration of its corresponding function parameter governs whether it can call a suspend function without a coroutine builder.  For example, here is a function that takes a no-arg function parameter:

```
fun f(g: () -> Unit)
```

If this function is called like so:

```
f {
    // do something
}
```

everything within the curly braces is executed as though it is within a function that is declared as:

```
fun g() {
    // do something
}
```

Since `g` is not declared with the `suspend` keyword, it cannot call a `suspend` function without using a coroutine builder.

However, if `f()` is declared thus:

```
fun f(g: suspend () -> Unit)
```

and is called like so:

```
f {
    // do something
}
```

everything within the curly braces is executed as though it is within a function that is declared as:

```
suspend fun g() {
    // do something
}
```

Since `g` *is* declared with the `suspend` keyword, it *can* call a `suspend` function without using a coroutine builder.

In the case of `addEventListener` the lambda is being called as though it is called within a function that is declared as:

```
public abstract void onEvent (T value, FirebaseFirestoreException error)
```

Since this function declaration does not have the `suspend` keyword (it can't, it is written in Java) then any lambda passed to it must use a coroutine builder to call a function declared with the `suspend` keyword.