# Why is the result not displayed on the screen after loading?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

When the application starts, in my case, nothing happens on the screen (a blank screen without data), but only for the user in logcat, it shows that data is being loaded from the server. As soon as I switch to another screen, the data appears for a split second and disappears, and when I return back to the "ForYouScreen" screen, the data appears. How it should be: The CircularProgressIndicator function should work first, then the data should be displayed.
I have provided the code below:

```
class NewsRepositoryImpl : NewsRepository {
    override fun getNewsArticles(): Flow<Resource<List<NewsArticle?>>> {
        val newsList: MutableList<NewsArticle?> = mutableListOf()
        var temp: List<NewsArticle?>
        val db: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        return flow{
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            db.collection("newsArticles").get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { queryDocumentSnapshots ->
                    if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty) {
                        val list = queryDocumentSnapshots.documents
                        for (d in list) {
                            val c: NewsArticle? = d.toObject(NewsArticle::class.java)
                            newsList.add(c)
                        }
                    }
                }
            temp = newsList
            emit(Resource.Success(temp))
        }.catch {
            emit(Resource.Error(it.message.toString()))
        }
    }
}
```

```
class GetNewsArticlesUseCase(
    private val repository: NewsRepository
) {
    operator fun invoke(): Flow<Resource<List<NewsArticle?>>> {
        return repository.getNewsArticles()
    }
}
```

```
class ForYouScreenViewModel(
    private val getNewsArticlesUseCase: GetNewsArticlesUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _state = mutableStateOf(ForYouState())
    val state: State<ForYouState> = _state

    init {
        loadNewsArticles()
    }

    private fun loadNewsArticles() {
        getNewsArticlesUseCase().onEach { result ->
            when(result){
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    _state.value = ForYouState(newsArticles = result.data ?: emptyList())
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    _state.value = ForYouState(isLoading = true)
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    _state.value = ForYouState(error = result.message ?: "An unexpected error occurred")
                }
            }
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}

data class ForYouState(
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val newsArticles: List<NewsArticle?> = emptyList(),
    val error: String = ""
)
```

```
@Composable
fun ForYouScreen(
    externalRouter: Router,
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    viewModel: ForYouScreenViewModel = koinViewModel()
) {
    val state = viewModel.state.value

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            items(state.newsArticles) { item ->
                AsyncImage(model = item?.image, contentDescription = null)
                item?.title?.let { Text(text = it) }
            }
        }
        if(state.error.isNotBlank()) {
            Text(
                text = state.error,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }
        if(state.isLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
        }
    }
}
```

I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: Since you're using Jetpack Compose, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).

Answer (score 1):

While I have never used Jetpack Compose, I'm pretty sure the `emit(Resource.Success(temp))` call now happens before the data is loaded. Try moving it inside the callback:

```
return flow{
    emit(Resource.Loading())
    db.collection("newsArticles").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { queryDocumentSnapshots ->
            if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty) {
                val list = queryDocumentSnapshots.documents
                for (d in list) {
                    val c: NewsArticle? = d.toObject(NewsArticle::class.java)
                    newsList.add(c)
                }
                temp = newsList
                emit(Resource.Success(temp))
            }
        }
}.catch {
    emit(Resource.Error(it.message.toString()))
}
```

Comment: If I do as you wrote, I will get an error: Suspend functions can only be called inside the body of a coroutine.

Comment: Did you search for that error message already, especially in combination with Firestore?

Comment: Here is the most similar problem to me, but the answer to it did not help me in any way: [Suspending function can only be called within coroutine body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60382882/suspending-function-can-only-be-called-within-coroutine-body). They answer that I need to place my emit call back into the context of a coroutine using whatever method you see fit (e.g. launch), or perhaps run a callbackFlow that will allow you to offer objects from other threads. Maybe I'm doing something wrong that your answer doesn't work for me?

Comment: Coroutines can be launched from Composables, use a Side effect.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects

Comment: If I put a delay of 10 seconds, then everything works, I mean that the loading is displayed and then the data appears! Can you explain why this is happening and how to avoid the artificial delay?